# Can anything other than Native Token be sent with internal transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, etherscan, evm, polygon

Can anything other than Native Currency（ETH, Matic and so） be sent with internal transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, native currencies are the only thing that is sent, ever.

Every other erc20 or erc721 tokens are just storage location of a smart contract being changed.
Just a balanceOf value that subtracts the amount sent from the sender and add it to the receiver.

But you can call .transfer() in an internal function.

What do you mean by 'be sent with internal transactions'? Try to be more specific

Comment: Thank you.

When looking at Seaport transactions in Etherscan, there is no tab for internal tx if the payment currency is set to an ERC20 token such as WETH. However, when a NATIVE currency is set, there is an internal transaction tab.

This fact led me to the following. Is this correct? 
1. When an ERC20 token is sent by the internal tx, it can be tracked in the event log. And there is no internal tx tab in Etherscan. 
2. When a native currency is sent by the internal tx, it is only shown in the internal tx tab. Sometimes it can be traced from the event log, but often it cannot.